# How to adjust the size and position of special symbols in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, latex, symbols

```
ax2.set_ylabel(r'Rainfall frequency(%)($\blacksquare$)', color=c2,fontsize=fontsize)
```

I use matplotlib to draw a multi-line chart with dual y-axes.I want to use different symbols on the y-axis label text to correspond to different line chart markers, so that the polyline and the y-coordinate axis can correspond better.
**However, the size and position of the symbol of the y-axis label cannot be modified.** **For example, I want to adjust my triangle to the top and bottom center of the text, and adjust the size of the square to be smaller.**

[image]

***How can I achieve this in latex syntax?***

I tried to add the command `\scriptsize` in front of `\blacksquare`, but an error message prompted me that the `\` in front of `scriptsize` was not recognized.

`ax2.set_ylabel(r'Rainfall frequency(%)($\scriptsize\blacksquare$)', color=c2,fontsize=fontsize)`

```
ValueError: 
\scriptsize\blacksquare
^
Unknown symbol: \scriptsize, found '\'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

I've also tried using the following code and installing 'pylatex' package but that doesn't seem to work either

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command   
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape
matplotlib.pyplot.rc('text', usetex=True)
```